# Require input after each line during while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

During a while loop - how do i force input after each line.

Program is meant to help people to start writing a song. So program offers a randomly-selected key.
The user has the opportunity to request another key. I want the user to continue to have this opportunity until they are given a key they would like to use.

### At the moment it runs an infinite loop - with no opportunity for user input

```
import random
majorkeys = ['A major', 'Bb major', 'B major', 'C major', 'Db major', 'D major', 'Eb major', 'E major', 'F major',
             'Gb major', 'G major', 'Ab major']
minorkeys = ['A minor', 'Bb minor', 'B minor', 'C minor', 'Db minor', 'D minor', 'Eb minor', 'E minor', 'F minor',
             'Gb minor', 'G minor', 'Ab minor']
allkeys = ['A major', 'Bb major', 'B major', 'C major', 'Db major', 'D major', 'Eb major', 'E major', 'F major',
           'Gb major', 'G major', 'Ab major', 'A minor', 'Bb minor', 'B minor', 'C minor', 'Db minor', 'D minor',
           'Eb minor', 'E minor', 'F minor','Gb minor', 'G minor', 'Ab minor']

#Lydia - in reference to Lydian Mode.
print("""
Hey there, my name is Lydia,
I'm here to help you start a song!
    """)

knownkey = (input("Do you know what key you would like to start with? "))

if knownkey == "no":
    print("\nLet me help you get this song off the ground! Try start with:")
    print(random.choice(allkeys))
else:
    print("That's a great starting point! Nice Work!")

confirmkey = (input("Are you happy to continue with this key? "))

while (confirmkey) == "no":
    print("No worries! Lets do:")
    print(random.choice(allkeys)+" instead!")
else:
    print("Awesome")
```

Comment: assume you want to change `while` to `if` also you need to set the `confirmkey` in case of `no`

Comment: @GuyMetter Well, you never give the user another opportunity to change `confirmkey` inside the while-loop. Also, `allkeys = majorkeys + minorkeys` seems like less writing.

Comment: Change `while` to `if`

Comment: @Ajay this only reruns the code once - so not giving you the option to reject the next random key offered

Comment: @Epsi95 I don't understand what you mean by "set the confirmkey in case of no"

Comment: `print(random.choice(allkeys)+" instead!")` by this you are just printing but not actually setting the `confirmkey`

Answer (score 1):

Going off of whtat others have said you want to define confirm key inside the while loop so that when the user enters "yes" the while loop stops. You just have to define confirmkey to no before starting the loop so it is not undefined.

```
confirmkey = "no"

while (confirmkey) == "no":
    confirmkey = (input("Are you happy to continue with this key? "))
    print("No worries! Lets do:")
    print(random.choice(allkeys)+" instead!")
else:
print("Awesome")
```

Comment: LEGEND! - Am new to this world so really appreciate it!